# Factory(:some_factory) or FactoryGirl.create(:some_factory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Is there any difference between `Factory(:some_factory)` and `FactoryGirl.create(:some_factory)`?

`Factory(:some_factory)` was causing `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch` in one controller spec while `FactoryGirl.create(:some_factory)` was not causing it

Answer (score 3):

`Factory(:some_factory)` and `Factory.create(:some_factory)` were used in older versions of FactoryGirl but deprecated in favor of the current `FactoryGirl.create(:some_factory)` syntax.